# How to solve H14 error in Heroku?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, heroku

I am trying to deploy war file using spring boot app usng maven plugin in heroku.

The error code that I am getting on deploying it is:

> 2018-03-10T05:47:07.563714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=patiyati.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=ebb35d7d-1fff-484f-8f58-faccd506b002 fwd="171.76.43.17"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

my pom.xml is as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>Patiyati</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Patiyati</name>
    <description>Patiyati</description>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web with Tomcat + Embed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>patiyati</appName>
                    <warFile>target/Patiyati-1.0.war</warFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have gone through many similar questions and have tried implementing those but none was of use...
On using Heroku ps:scale web=1 -a patiyati 
I get "Couldn't find process type error"

I followed the steps given in the document [heroku deployment using maven plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin), but it provides me the same result.

On adding a procfile :

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.spring.app.SpringBootWebApplication
```

Where SpringBootWebApplication is my main class and is under com.spring.app package.

Now i get app crash as a result

> 2018-03-10T08:31:39.460117+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=patiyati.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=59d88594-c17f-4003-8527-722d780f475c fwd="171.76.43.17"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

It would be great if anybody could help me solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried scaling up the dyno from Heroku dashboard?

Comment: I did look into the dashboard but there was no way i could add it...
under resource tab it displays : This app has no process types yet
Add a Procfile to your app in order to define its process types.

Comment: Check my answer. Just noticed your `pom.xml`. Is there a specific reason why you're deploying your app as `war` instead of `jar`?

Comment: yea its one of the requirement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a Procfile in your application root directory with below entry and push the app.

`web: java -jar $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT target/your-app-name-version.jar`

**EDIT**

Just realized from your `pom.xml` that you're packaging as `war`. Please refer [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment) on `war` deployment to heroku.

Comment: i already went through the same document .. it again redirects to maven plugin deployment document.

Comment: have you tried the `heroku-cli` route with `heroku war:deploy <path_to_war_file> --app <app_name>` ?

Comment: gimme a minute i shall try that too

Comment: Did you install the plugin in the first place? `heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy`

Comment: yea... its already installed..... but yea i found out the error in there.... i had space between war: and deploy hence the erro

Comment: Whats the error are you getting now? I believe you should remove the procfile if using `war`

Comment: yea procfile must not be there as mentioned in the document... but if i don't include it gives error....

Comment: btw when I am uploading the same through Heroku dashboard why is it not working? got any clues?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get your question. What are you trying to upload via dashboard?

Comment: when i do the deployment of the same through heroku ... the app crashes in the same way as it used to as in the initail problem statement..

Comment: Probably something to do with the maven approach.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I removed `<packaging>war</packaging>` line from pom.xml then pushed and it started working. I hope it helps someone